# Blender bevel curves

Tags: modifiers, bevel, fcurves

I am trying to bevel a curve by selecting it in orange, but only one section will apply the bevel modifier,

[image]

I am using Blender 3.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

UPDATE

Here's the file.

http://shanegibney.com/shanegibney/dart.blend1

The reference images

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share your mesh

Comment: I suppose you have some doubled geometry, try selecting whole mesh and pressing M → By Distance.

Comment: How do I know I have double geometry? I went into object mode and clicked on the shape, I don't know if I am clicking on the object or the mesh and hitting 'm' It highlighted in orange. But no change unfortunately . Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: You click on the object in Object mode, and on the mesh in Edit mode.

Comment: OK got it hanks. Unfortunately the m in object mode doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Share the file then. We need to have a closer look

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to share file. I tried linking to them above but it doesn't work.

Comment: The reference images have also been included in the question.

Comment: . By copying and pasting the url above into a browser the file can be obtained. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see now. It is a combination of several issues.

First one. Is a doubled geometry, as I've deducted yet:

[image]

It is easy to remove. Select all vertices by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> in **Edit Mode** Then press <kbd>M</kbd> → By Distance

But that's not all.

Second issue. You have set limit by angle. 90 degrees is very unstable, some angle may be less than 90 some more 90 because of precision error. So set it to 89 for example.

But even that is not all.

After that, your bevel will be limited by minimal edge. In your case, that edge:

[image]

You have to decide what to do with that. Move edge or remove it, or live as it is.

Comment: It seems there are three points. 1. There is double  geometry as you suggested. This can be removed by going into edit mode and pressing m and selecting by distance. All done. 2. Setting the limit by angle. It should be less than 90. I've played with this doesn't seem to work. 3.Bevel limited by edge. I Wish to keep the edge. But how do I do this? The gifs are great for expalining. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 2. It will work if other problems are solved 3. You can allow overlapping in bevel modifier,  but in this case, faces will... overlap :-)